# Is it possible to create a promise loop until reject in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I wish to load ~10000 resources and doing this all at once during the resolve phase takes a bit too long due to certain calculations being done. So then I came to the idea to load the resources page by page sequentially, however since all these resources need to be visible (on a map) standard, user-input based pagination, doesn't really work.

I know that promises can be chained like:

```
promise.then(doThis).then(doThat).then(doWhat);
```

And I know that an array of promises can be resolved with `$q.all` like:

```
$q.all([doThis, doThat, doWhat]);
```

However what I want to is to call the same promise again and again in series until I hit a rejection.

Example:

```
function next() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  if(someCondition) {
    deferred.reject();
  } else {
    //do something
    //store data somewhere
    deferred.resolve();
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Let's say that this function does some `$http` calls and stores the result somewhere in the service/controller. If it hits a certain condition (perhaps there aren't any pages anymore or an http error) it rejects a promise, otherwise it resolves it.

Now I'd like to do something like this pseudocode

```
$q.loop(next).untilError(handleError);
```

Where `next` will be called in a loop upon resolving the previous `next` call, until rejection.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the console of this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvr60ey3/1/).

It ensures the calling of the APIs are using `userId` from 1 to 5 sequentially. And stop at some condition (`userId > 5`).

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    getUser(1, getUser);

    function getUser(userId, next) {
        if (userId > 5) {
            console.log('Enough. Stop');
            return;
        }
        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + userId).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.data);
            next(userId + 1, next);
        });
    }
}]);
```